# Design a custom annotation to invoke a method in a jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I'm a bit new to annotations in Java. Is it possible to design a custom annotation which when used in a class automatically invokes a method  present inside another Class. TIA.

Comment: annotation is only a "marker", in sense is not active code, some engine (library / code) must "interpret" usually with "reflection" and do actions You want

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "sort of": annotations by themselves do **nothing** (except "compile time" annotations that affect the **compile** process).

Meaning: just attaching an annotation to something doesn't magically cause a method to be called at some arbitrary point in time.

This works differently: you have some sort of **framework** - and at some point you ask the framework to process an object, class, ... And then the framework might check for the presence of certain annotations to "do" something based on that check.

Thus: it is possible to implement custom annotations, and it is also possible to make some "framework" *react* to the presence of that annotation.

In case you find this answer too generic - well, it can't be more precise/specific than the question ...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand that annotations are just markers or a replacement of XML for holding the meta data in class level. I will make my question more precise and explanatory.

Example:
    If there a class A and an annotation @ callA. I want to use @ callA inside another class B to call a block(may be a static block) inside class A.  I just thought of this idea because I saw a couple of examples where there were class and method definition inside @ interface. I'm still learning more about annotations in Java. May be, my idea would be wrong. Just experimenting. TIA